# Как сделать горизонтальный слайдинг экрана в Activity

Tags: android, eclipse

Есть много TextView на всю активити. В дизайнере Eclipse он входит ровно в экран, но при запуске на телефоне помещается часть TextView, остальных не видно. И соответственно вертикальная прокрутка так же не работает. Куда копать, какой параметр прописывать?

Comment: Покажите ваш лайаут и опишите какое конкретно поведение нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите ваш layout в ScrollView, будет скролл